# Check whether a map contains not null values for only a set of keys

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I have a map as below

```
Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();
myMap.put("a", "Something");
myMap.put("b", null);
myMap.put("c", "more");
```

and a list,

```
List<String> myList = Arrays.asList("a","b");
```

I want to check, whether all the values in myMap with keys in myList are null

I have created a method as follows and it works fine. I wanted to check whether we can achieve the same in one line of code using stream

```
myMap.values().removeIf(Objects::isNull);

Map<String, String> resultMap = myList.stream().filter(myMap::containsKey).collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), myMap::get));
if(!resultMap.isEmpty()){
// Atleast one not null value is present in myMap with key in myList
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Sure, simply check if all elements in the list match a non-null value from the map:

```
myList.stream().allMatch(x -> myMap.containsKey(x) && myMap.get(x) == null);
// or (more overhead, but you might prefer its expressivness):
myList.stream()
    .filter(myMap::containsKey)
    .map(myMap::get)
    .allMatch(Objects::isNull);
```

Or, if you consider "missing keys" to be equivalent to "having null":

```
myList.stream().map(myMap::get).allMatch(Objects:isNull);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Map.get` specifies that keys that aren't present return null. So you can filter out keys mapped to null or not mapped at all with just one null check.

```
Map<String, String> resultMap = myList.stream()
    .filter(key -> myMap.get(key) != null)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), myMap::get));
```

If you don't need a `resultMap` it's even shorter with `anyMatch`

```
myList.stream().allMatch(key -> myMap.get(key) != null)
```

Unlike `myMap.values().removeIf(Objects::isNull)` this will not modify the original map.

Answer (score 1):

So, you've removed the entries having `null` *values* with this line:

```
myMap.values().removeIf(Objects::isNull);
```

Fine, since keeping null-references in the collections an antipattern because these elements can't provide any useful information. So I consider this was your intention unrelated to checking if all the string in `myList` were associated with `null` (or not present).

Now to check whether `myMap` contain any of the elements from `myList` (which would automatically imply that the *value* mapped to such element is *non-null*) you can create a stream over the contents of `myList` and check each element against the *key-set* of `myMap`:

```
boolean hasNonNullValue = myList.stream().anyMatch(myMap.keySet()::contains);
```

I suspect you might to perform some actions with such *keys* (if any). If so, then instead of performing a check provided above would make sense to generate a list of these *keys*:

```
List<String> keysToExamine = myList.stream()
    .filter(myMap.keySet()::contains)
    .toList(); // for JDK versions earlier then 16 use .collect(Collectors.toList()) instead of toList()
```

***Note***: check elements of the *list* against the *key-set*, **not** the opposite, otherwise you might cause performance degradation.

Answer (score 1):

#### [`Stream#findAny`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findAny--) and [`Optional#ifPresent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresent-java.util.function.Consumer-)

It seems you want to perform some action if at least one non-null value is present in `myMap` with the corresponding key in `myList`. If yes, this combination meets your requirement perfectly.

```
myMap.keySet()
    .stream()
    .filter(k -> myMap.get(k) != null && myList.contains(k))
    .findAny()
    .ifPresent(
        // Atleast one not null value is present in myMap with key in myList
        System.out::println // A sample action
    );
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://ideone.com/Ds1X0a)</kbd>